# Problems with italicizing specialized glyphs because tipa doesn't have italicized form

Tags: italic, tipa

I am fighting with some vocabulary that requires special glyphs, the problem being that in my document I am required to present all vocabulary examples in italics and `tipa` doesn't do italics. Since this is a style requirement I would appreciate a solution that doesn't involve me changing every vocabulary example in a 400 page document on vocabulary to slanted (quite apart from the fact that I find that slanted doesn't really make the words stand out nearly as well as italic does and it's not pretty). I am inclined to find some solution including `math` but I would probably incur the wrath of proper form. Any ideas appreciated.

These are the offenders:

[image]

And here is some code including my settings and what I have tried:

```
 \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[LY1,T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    the main offenders with italics:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  *\textit{\textcrb l\={e}waz} (indo-european)
        \item \textit{polv\textsoftsign} (slavic)
        \item *\textit{\textyogh allan} (indo-european)
        \item *\textit{\textroundcap{g}hel} (indo-european)
        \item \textit{khol\textacutemacron{e}} (greek)
        \item *\textit{pa\textcrd\textcrd\={o}n} (indo-european)
    \end{itemize}
    
    Slanted doesn't work either. 
    neither using slanted straight up: (the accent ones look a little better but not much):
    \begin{itemize}
        \item *\textsl{\textcrb l\={e}waz} (indo-european)
        \item \textsl{polv\textsoftsign} (slavic)
        \item *\textsl{\textyogh allan} (indo-european)
    \end{itemize}

    nor the \textipa{} command (doesn't even slant)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textipa{*\textsl{\textroundcap{g}hel}} (indo-european)
        \item \textsl{\textipa{khol\textacutemacron{e}}} (greek)
        \item *\textipa{\textsl{pa\textcrd\textcrd\={o}n}} (indo-european)
    \end{itemize}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: There is slanted, is it good as well? It works, provided you do a small adjustment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slanted works, provided you help LaTeX in finding the right font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr}

\begin{document}

Slanted works
\begin{itemize}
\item  *\textsl{\textcrb l\={e}waz} (indo-european)
\item \textsl{polv\textsoftsign} (slavic)
\item *\textsl{\textyogh allan} (indo-european)
\item *\textsl{\textroundcap{g}hel} (indo-european)
\item \textsl{khol\textacutemacron{e}} (greek)
\item *\textsl{pa\textcrd\textcrd\={o}n} (indo-european)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a specialized font available, which sports italic type.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{linguisticspro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}

\newcommand{\tipait}[1]{\textit{\textipa{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Italic  works, both with \verb|\textit|
\begin{itemize}
\item  *\textit{\textcrb l\={e}waz} (indo-european)
\item \textit{polv\textsoftsign} (slavic)
\item *\textit{\textyogh allan} (indo-european)
\item *\textit{\textroundcap{g}hel} (indo-european)
\item \textit{khol\textacutemacron{e}} (greek)
\item *\textit{pa\textcrd\textcrd\={o}n} (indo-european)
\end{itemize}
and \verb|\tipait|
\begin{itemize}
\item  *\tipait{\textcrb l\={e}waz} (indo-european)
\item \tipait{polv\textsoftsign} (slavic)
\item *\tipait{\textyogh allan} (indo-european)
\item *\tipait{\textroundcap{g}hel} (indo-european)
\item \tipait{khol\textacutemacron{e}} (greek)
\item *\tipait{pa\textcrd\textcrd\={o}n} (indo-european)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but these are six problematic words with slanted out of hundreds which I use italic for :| Getting them to slant is fine as long as I am prepared to go through my document and change all the other ones to slanted for consistency and then fight my entire doctoral committee on it. :p

Comment: @Plergux An experienced user would have `\newcommand{\myipa}[1]{\textit{#1}}` in the preamble and `\myipa{polv\textsoftsign}` in the document body. Better yet, perhaps, `\textit{\textipa{#1}}`. Upon realizing the issue, it would be sufficient to change `\textit` to `\textsl` in the definition. Lessons one learns… ;-)

Comment: @Plergux If you're keen on changing fonts, there is LinguisticsPro. I'll add an example.

Comment: It'll take a little getting used to, but it does what I want :p Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has already been answered, this is more of an afterword.

Fonts and characters have always been  tricky to deal with.

Instead of using last-century legacy fonts, what would a more modern, Unicode-based, solution look like?

And a random sample of half a dozen fonts shows the amount of work a font-designer puts into the font, and that, in some cases and combinations, some hand-crafting of specific glyphs/combinations might still be needed in the interim.

[image: noto serif]

[image: junicode]

[image: linguistics pro]

[image: dejavu serif]

[image: gentium plus]

[image: liberation serif]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\fnamea{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\fnameb{Junicode}
\newcommand\fnamec{Linguistics Pro}
\newcommand\fnamed{DejaVu Serif}
\newcommand\fnamee{Gentium Plus}
\newcommand\fnamef{Liberation Serif}

\newfontfamily\ffonta{\fnamea}
\newfontfamily\ffontb{\fnameb}
\newfontfamily\ffontc{\fnamec}
\newfontfamily\ffontd{\fnamed}
\newfontfamily\ffonte{\fnamee}
\newfontfamily\ffontf{\fnamef}

\setmainfont{\fnamea}

\newcommand\cdmacuteaccent{\symbol{769}}
\newcommand\cdmmacron{\symbol{772}}
\newcommand\cdminvertedbreve{\symbol{785}}
\newcommand\bwithstroke{\symbol{384}}%ƀ}
\newcommand\dwithstroke{\symbol{273}}%đ}
\newcommand\ewithmacron{\symbol{275}}%ē}
\newcommand\owithmacron{\symbol{333}}%ō}
\newcommand\cyrsoftsign{\symbol{1100}}%ь}
\newcommand\lebyogh{\symbol{541}}%ȝ}
\newcommand\ewithmacronandacute{\symbol{7703}}%ē}


%----------------
\newcommand\mybwithstroke{\textit{b}\kern-0.6em{\raisebox{0.35em}{\textit{-}}}\hspace{0.12em}}
\newcommand\mylebyogh{{\ffontd\textit{\symbol{541}}}}%ȝ}
%----------------



\newcommand\mytexta{\bwithstroke le\cdmmacron waz}
\newcommand\mytextb{polv\cyrsoftsign}
\newcommand\mytextc{\lebyogh allan}
\newcommand\mytextd{g\cdminvertedbreve hel}
\newcommand\mytexte{khole\cdmmacron\cdmacuteaccent} \newcommand\mytextf{pa\dwithstroke\dwithstroke o\cdmmacron n}

\newcommand\doexample{%
\hspace{1.5em}\begin{tabular}{|cccc}
*\mytexta &
*\itshape\mytexta &
*\bfseries\mytexta &
*\itshape\bfseries\mytexta \\
\mytextb &
\itshape\mytextb &
\bfseries\mytextb &
\itshape\bfseries\mytextb \\
\ *\mytextc &
*\itshape\mytextc &
*\bfseries\mytextc &
*\itshape\bfseries\mytextc \\
\ *\mytextd &
*\itshape\mytextd &
*\bfseries\mytextd &
*\itshape\bfseries\mytextd \\
\mytexte &
\itshape\mytexte &
\bfseries\mytexte &
\itshape\bfseries\mytexte \\
\ *\mytextf &
*\itshape\mytextf &
*\bfseries\mytextf &
*\itshape\bfseries\mytextf \\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

Using font \fnamea 
\begin{itemize}
\item  *\textit{\mytexta} (indo-european)
:
\ewithmacron e\cdmmacron
\item \textit{\mytextb} (slavic)
\item *\textit{\mytextc} (indo-european)
\item *\textit{\mytextd} (indo-european)
\item \textit{khol\ewithmacronandacute\ \mytexte} (greek)
\item *\textit{\mytextf} (indo-european)
: \textit{\owithmacron o\cdmmacron} 
\end{itemize}

\ffonta Using font \fnamea
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffontb Using font \fnameb
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffontc Using font \fnamec
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffontd Using font \fnamed
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffonte Using font \fnamee
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffontf Using font \fnamef
\bigskip
\doexample

\ffontc Using font \fnamec

Original: \textit{\mytexta}

Construction: \textit{b} + \textit{-} = \mybwithstroke\ 
$\mapsto$
\mybwithstroke\textit{le\cdmmacron waz}
\bigskip

Original: \textit{\mytextc}

Construction: other font \mylebyogh\ + \textit{allan} $\mapsto$
\mylebyogh\textit{allan}

\end{document}
```

*Addendum*

Adding hand-crafted forms to fill the gaps is sometimes a possibility.

For example, for the two gaps in Linguistics Pro, existing b + - can be joined together, and yogh can be borrowed from another font

```
%----------------
\newcommand\mybwithstroke{\textit{b}\kern-0.6em{\raisebox{0.35em}{\textit{-}}}\hspace{0.12em}}

\newcommand\mylebyogh{{\ffontd\textit{\symbol{541}}}}%ȝ}
%----------------
```

giving:

[image: fillingthegaps]

Comment: Thank you for this postscript :) As a speaker of a language with "special" characters I often base my judgement of fonts at least partially on what glyphs they have available. Many fonts get discarded right away if they don't have a Þ or an ð (and I go through a lot of fonts XD). But as your example shows, even a font called Linguistics Pro doesn't even account for what is needed in a linguistics dissertation. And then fonts also have to pass my aesthetics scrutiny which is very picky :p Not all fonts can be Latin Modern :p

Comment: @Plergux Likewise with me :) . And sometimes, when circumstances allow, handcrafted forms can be constructed to fill the gaps. I've added a small example to the answer. Most basic fallback would be an `\includegraphics`, based on what I have seen elsewhere on this site.